# How do I understand this piece of code to reverse a linked list with recursion?

Tags: algorithm, recursion

```
Node* reverse(Node* node)
    {
        if (node == NULL)
            return NULL;
        if (node->next == NULL) {
            head = node;
            return node;
        }
        Node* node1 = reverse(node->next);
        node1->next = node;
        node->next = NULL;
        return node;
    }
```

I can understand first two if statements but the sentence of `Node* node1 = reverse(node->next);` runs, I think it will call it self and then execute first two if statements. So when the last three lines `node1->next = node;node->next = NULL;return node;` execute?

A bit confused here >_<

Answer (score 0):

It is [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion).

Function calls itself with smaller sublist, reverse it, then glues reversed one with current node.

```
A -> B...Z
separate A node and  list B...Z
reverse B...Z
Z...B
append A node
Z....B -> A
```

Comment: I am confused because based on my understanding, the last three lines never had a chance to execute.

Comment: They are executed when there are some elements in the list (>1). The first `if` returns when list is empty, The second `if` returns when list contains the only element. Otherwise the rest does work.

Comment: Provided that the list > 1 and it will execute ``Node* node1 = reverse(node->next);``   At this point, it will call it self so it will not jump to the beginning of the function but it will execute the next line ``node1->next = node;``? I'm confused about the mechaism T-T

Comment: When you have list A-B-NULL, function calls itself `reverse(node->next)` with argument B, at the second recursion level returns from the second `if` because length is 1, node1 becomes B-NULL after recursive call, then B joins to A:  B-A, then A.next becomes NULL, so finally B-A-NULL.

Comment: You can step over code and see line sequence `2-4-8-(2-4-5-6)-8-9-10-11`.  The sequence in brackets is executed at the second recursion level

Comment: Now I have a new concept. ``Node* node1 = reverse(node->next);`` will return a node, and do something for this node. After several times,  ``reverse(node->next);`` will return null or head. At this time, I will know the value of pervious time that the ``reverse(node->next);`` returns, and then the pervious pervious value I will know, and so on.